# Capture e-mail sent using PHP mailer and smtp relay

Tags: php, phpmailer, wireshark

I have a HTML form which on submit sends e-mail using PHP Mailer. i use a SMTP relay address to send my e-mail. I need to use wireshark to capture ports and/or addresses visited/opened when form is submitted.

What i tried as capture filters is:

```
Tcp.port==smtp
Ip.src == my-webserver-address (same for ip.addr)
Http.request.method==“POST”
```

But i cannot see any smtp results after form submission

What i would like to see is the ip address that PhP mailer uses as smtp relay to send e-mail and check ports used and/or external links opened during this procedure

Comment: If you're submitting via authenticated SMTP, you're probably (and should be) using port 587 or 465, which may not be covered by that `smtp` value, which is probably 25.

Comment: Yes but shouldn’t smtp filter to show everything?

Comment: While it says `smtp`, it's being assigned to `Tcp.port`, suggesting it's a single number, and that may not be the port number you're sending on; try the other values I suggested. You can always find out by capturing all traffic and looking at what it is using.